# Could the mobile emitter in Voyager be used by any program created on the holodeck?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, technology, hologram

In the *Star Trek: Voyager* episode, "[Future's End, Part II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Future%27s_End,_Part_II_(episode))", Voyager's EMH, the Doctor, was able to leave sickbay or the holodeck and roam freely with the help of a mobile emitter (the technology originating in the 29th century). Could this be used by any hologram created on the holodeck?

Comment: I hope so! Let’s get that Irish bartender wandering around, occasionally making longing looks at Janeway in the cafeteria.

Comment: Oh, wait, [they did that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/255400/440)

Comment: I'm thinking my very own holographic  coffee cup. I suppose you could stick a butler onto the coffee cup too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mobile emitter was evidently compatible with other holodeck characters, as it enabled the USS Voyager's [Leonardo da Vinci hologram](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci_(hologram)) to walk around on a planet's surface, far from any other holoemitters, in the *Voyager* Season 4 episode, "[Concerning Flight](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Concerning_Flight_(episode))".

The mobile emitter also proved compatible with the [USS Equinox's](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Equinox) EMH (VOY: "[Equinox](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Equinox_(episode))"), the [Michael Sullivan hologram](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_Sullivan) (VOY: "[Spirit Folk](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spirit_Folk_(episode))"), the [Reginald Barclay hologram](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Reginald_Barclay_(hologram)) (VOY: "[Inside Man](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Inside_Man_(episode))"), and [Iden](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Iden), a hologram created by the [Hirogen](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hirogen), using Starfleet holographic technology (VOY: "[Flesh and Blood](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Flesh_and_Blood_(episode))").

Comment: Not recalling those other instances but a notable distinction is the EMH program can self activate and shutdown the hologram.  The nonplayer character holograms in theory should not have the ability, knowledge, or desire to prefer an emitter or prefer to be activated.

Comment: And presumably a mere character should be a vastly smaller program vs something as sophisticated as an EMH regardless of the sentient vs non-sentient issues.

Comment: Also Marayna (a holographic character controlled by an alien) was able to briefly use the emitter in Alter Ego, to visit Tuvok in his quarters after her program was "deleted".